# ERROR in Error: AppModule is not an NgModule - Angular-cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am working on a web application using Angular 4 with angular-cli. Since last week I started getting following error which I am trying to fix:

*ERROR in Error: AppModule is not an NgModule
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (D:.Net Projects\Angular 2\engineUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:140:15)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (D:.Net Projects\Angular 2\engineUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (D:.Net Projects\Angular 2\engineUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (D:.Net Projects\Angular 2\engineUI\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (D:.Net Projects\Angular 2\engineUI\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:241:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (D:.Net Projects\Angular 2\engineUI\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:4
95:24)
    at*

I have tried various option such as run as admin, clean NPM cache but I am still getting this error on ng build command.

My node version is : v8.9.1
NPM version: 5.6.0
Angular-cli: 1.6.0

package.json file:

```
{
"name": "recommendation-engine",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.85",
"angular2-highlight-js": "^5.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"ngx-loading": "^1.0.8",
"ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "^6.0.92",
"codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
}
```

.angular-cli.json file

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"project": {
"name": "engine"
},
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}
],
"e2e": {
"protractor": {
  "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
}
},
"lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
}
],
"test": {
"karma": {
  "config": "./karma.conf.js"
}
},
"defaults": {
"styleExt": "css",
"component": {}
}
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: I had this problem after an update. I then deleted the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json, and then did a clean "npm install"

Comment: Thanks Tim it worked... :)

Comment: Great ! I'll add an answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem after an update. I then **deleted the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json**, and then did a clean

```
npm install
```

The culprit was indeed the package-lock.json in my case. It gets worse when multiple people work on the project and this file is not checked in !